# How to validate birthday using certain conditions. Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am currently working on my ruby on rails assignment and I have this form where user must enter what division they want to join in (Junior or Senior) and their birthday. Now, what I want to do is to validate their birthday according to the division they want to join. For example if the user selects the Junior division, he/she must be 15 to 20 years old and if Senior, he/she must be 20 to 25 years old. I tried different syntax from the internet but nothing is working. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can't help you without your draft.

Comment: front end or backend validations?

Comment: the one in the model.

Comment: validates :birthday, :presence =>{:if => {:junior? =>{:message => 'You should be 15 to 20 years old.'}}}

def midget?()
        :division == "Junior"
end

This is what I have right now

Answer (score 0):

Here's some logic.. hard to see without some sort of code

You can work out their age by doing:

```
age = (currentyear - birthday year value)
```

Possible validation something like:

```
if (age > 15 and < 20 and selected=senior) {
 //error you are junior
}
 else if (age > 20 and < 25 and select=junior){
 //error you are senior
}
```

Again not a complete answer but see if you can do something with the logic and ruby syntax...

Comment: validate :validate_birthday

private

def validate_birthday
   if birthday.present? && division == "Midget" && birthday < 15.years.ago.to_i && birthday > 18.years.ago.to_i
      errors.add(:birthday, 'You should be 15 to 18 years old to register for this division.')
   end